# Font-face bug on IE - Angular 5

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts

I am getting an error on IE in my project, for the first time ever and it goes like this:

```
@font-face encountered unknown error.
HelveticaLTStd-Roman.92fa3700314207f8e4a0.eot

CSS3114: @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable.
HelveticaLTStd-Roman.6dd14b27b222326b5c19.otf

Unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference
inline.bundle.js (55,12)
```

I found some answers but nothing that really helped me, I implemented fonts like always, example:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'HelveticaLTStd-Roman';
  src: url('../fonts/HelveticaLTStd-Roman.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../fonts/HelveticaLTStd-Roman.otf')  format('opentype'),
  url('../fonts/HelveticaLTStd-Roman.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/HelveticaLTStd-Roman.ttf')  format('truetype'),
  url('../fonts/HelveticaLTStd-Roman.svg#HelveticaLTStd-Roman') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Anyone knows whats going on, and how to fix it?